# Can a cat be trained to use a leash?

Tags: cats, leash-training

Can a cat be walked with a leash?  If so, how can I train a cat to use a leash?

Comment: Related: [Why is it not common for cats to be taken for walks?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2919/why-is-it-not-common-for-cats-to-be-taken-for-walks/)

Comment: Is the answer to your question at [How can I help a cat who seems afraid of his harness?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3056)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a leash on a cat; I do it all the time. It's best to start them out at a younger age, but even if they are adult cats, they can still be trained by using a harness and a leash.  Try starting out slow, like walking them around the yard with a harness and leash. For awhile, they may just roll over or lay down; just pick them back up and place them in a standing position.  I t takes a while to get used to the harness and leash.   Cat treats could help to promote a good response.